# How can I pick an Image in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to save an image inside a database, I wrote this code to select the image and save it in a variable of type XFILE, this is the code:

```
Future<XFile?> pickImage(String inputSource) async{

  final XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: inputSource == 'camera' ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery);

  if(pickedImage == null){

    return null;

  }else{

    return pickedImage;

  }

}
```

Could you tell me why it works on Android and not on IOS? On IOS it is as if it did not select the image. This is the exception on IOS:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, XFILE is not the same as a FILE, so the problem can came from there. Check this example and use the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin as a recommendation to avoid Unhandled Exceptions.

```js
_openCamera({fromCamera=true}) async{

        File finalImage;

        XFile image = fromCamera //bolean to open from camera or gallery
                ? await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 800, maxWidth: 800, imageQuality: 100)
                : await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxHeight: 640, maxWidth: 640, imageQuality: 60);

         finalImage = File(image.path); //convert XFILE to FILE

        if(image!=null) {
            setState(() {
                this._yourFile = finalImage;
            });
        }
    }
```